# What was Leticia's emotion at the end?

Tags: monsters-ball

In [Monster's Ball (2001)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0285742/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt), Leticia finds the drawings her husband gave Hank and Sonny. It looked like she was mad at first, but then at the end more in awe. Hank told her, "I think we're going to be ok" and she sat there as if she agreed.

So, what was her emotion?

Comment: https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/monstersball.pdf